# Upload file to Server in Dropzone only after whole file is received

Tags: dropzone.js, dropzone

I am using dropzone.js in a form and the uploading to the server is being executed correctly. However, I need to be able to process the file uploaded before sending it to the server to get more information from the user. I need to show thumbnails for example for the pdf uploaded so requiring the whole pdf before sending. I tried to remove the action link, and generate the link in a method given to dropzone. It did not work. The form always uploads directly to the server while the upload is happening on the web browser. How to disable that?

My code looks like the following

```
<form id="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">

</form>
```

and JS

```
Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "true",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : "true",
            "session": sessionId
        },
        acceptedFiles: "application/pdf",
        url:getUrl
}
```

and getURL returns the url but gets called when the file uploaded has not been uploaded to the browser yet. Is there a way to upload the file completely and then send to the server directly from the browser

Comment: what language u are using at server side ?  Node JS ?

Comment: Clojure, but does it make a difference ? The server recieves the requests without problem.